# Binding Map<String, String>

Tags: path-variables

In controller methods, If the method parameter is

```
 @PathVariable Map<String, String>
```

then the map is populated with all path variable names and values. 
Is this true?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`@PathVariable` is to differentiate endpoints and should not be used to send collection data to controller e.g. assume one of my endpoint as `/list/{vehicletype}/{fuel}`
Here both `{vehicletype}` and `{fuel}` are path variables.

Now if i use car as vehicletype and petrol as fuel my endpoint is `/list/car/petrol` to get list of all car running on petrol
Also i can pass bike as vehicletype and electric as fuel to list all bikes that run on electricity. My endpoint is such condition will be `/list/bike/electric`

So you can see that same endpoint is made dynamic with help of path variables. Also as path variable uses data in browser url, so it will choke with 1028 characters.

If you need to send data to controller use `@RequestBody` instead. If you want to validate it for emptiness for data validation, implement your own validator and use `@Valid` annotation

Answer (score 1):

> The map is populated with all path variable names and values. Is this true?

You always can try it out. But in short, the answer is *yes*. From the [`@PathVariable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) documentation:

> Annotation which indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a URI template variable. Supported for [`RequestMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) annotated handler methods.
>
> If the method parameter is [`Map<String, String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) then the map is populated with all path variable names and values.

Consider the following controller method:

```java
@GetMapping("/{param1}/{param2}")
public ResponseEntity<Void> get(@PathVariable Map<String, String> values) {
    System.out.println(values);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

For a request such as:

```
GET /foo/bar HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
```

It will print:

```java
{param1=foo, param2=bar}
```

Answer (score 1):

**@PathVariable** is a Spring annotation which indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a URI template variable. *If the method parameter is Map then the map is populated with all path variable names and values.*

**Example :**

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@GetMapping(value = "/book/{author}/{title}")
public void process3(@PathVariable Map<String, String> vals) {

  logger.info("{}: {}", vals.get("author"), vals.get("title"));

}
```